# Python - is there a function similar to list.index() that is not affected by duplicated values in a list?

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7

`list.index()` will give you the index of the first time the value is shown in the list, but I am looking for a way  that will return the index of that specific item, regardless of whether it is repeated, for example, if  were to use it like so:

```
lst = [1,4,5,1,4]

for i in lst:
    lst.something(i)
```

would return

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: No, it's not possible for `lst.something(1)` to know whether to return `0` or `3` depending on *which* `1` it was called with. `int` is a primitive type, so `1` is just the same as another `1`.

Comment: Is there no way for a for loop to know what item it is currently performing the function on? If there is, can it not return that value?

Comment: In that case, you want `enumerate` (see @D.Shawley's answer below)

Comment: Would I be right in saying that enumerate only works with iterations? Is there a similar function I can use that doesn't require it to be part of a loop?

Comment: Yes, enumerate works only with iterations. What you're asking for isn't possible; please see my answer.

Comment: You should step back and examine why you want this function.  There's definitely a better way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Perhaps there is, I'm trying to write my own sort function, to practice writing algorithms

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate)?

```
>>> lst = [1,4,5,1,4]
>>> for index, elm in enumerate(lst):
...  print index, elm
...
0 1
1 4
2 5
3 1
4 4
>>>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the question- I think the question is for `lst.something(lst[0])` to return `0`, and `lst.something(lst[3])` to return `3`, which isn't possible.

Comment: @DavidRobinson - Of course it's not possible, but usually it's because the OP is looking for the functionality behind enumerate in whatever they're doing.

Comment: @DavidRobinson If you read the reply to your comment on the OP, I think you're wrong. :)

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yes, that is what I was looking for actually; so there is no way to achieve that? Even by defining a new function?

Answer (score 2):

use enumerate

```
for i,_ in enumerate(listt):
    print i
```

Comment: I'd prefer `in range(len(listt))`

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible for `lst.something(1)` to know whether to return 0 or 3 depending on which 1 it was called with. `int` is a primitive type, so any `1` is just the same as another `1`.

As proof, you can use the `is` operator:

```
lst = [1, 4, 5, 1, 4]
print lst[0] is lst[3]
# True
```

So when the hypothetical function `lst.something(1)` is called, it won't know which `1` you meant, regardless of how you called it.

Comment: Even if `is` *didn't* return `True` -- say for two distinct but equal `int` objects -- you'd still be right.  I think equality is the right condition, not identity.  `enumerate` is the right way to get as close as we can in practice, but the fact that there's not going to be a way to tell which element we're referring to is inescapable.  (Assuming random access, anyway: we could make a stateful indexer which remembers where it was, or what it's yielded, etc, but I'd need to see a use case because I suspect there would be a simpler way to get there, wherever 'there' would be.)

Comment: Note that your `is` test returning True is a CPython implementation detail; for larger values for `int()` that won't be true at all, in any Python implementation.